# js object property creation from keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

hi I am trying to create a object map from array of objects using reduce method but did n't find a way to add 2 properties as key . Let  say I have array of objects like -

```
 const students = [
    {
      name: "sam",
      age: 26,
    },
    {
      name: "john",
      age: 30,
    }
    ]
```

i am trying to create a map like

```
{
  sam_26:{
      name: "sam",
      age: 26,
    }
 }
```

my code for reduce function :

```
students.reduce((obj, student) => {
    `${obj[student.name]}_${obj[student.age]}` = student;
    return obj;
  }, {});
```

this didn't work . any pointers will be helpful ..thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the key with the values taken from the `student` object. Assign the current `student` to the `obj` (the accumulator) using the `key`:

```js
const students = [{
    name: "sam",
    age: 26,
  },
  {
    name: "john",
    age: 30,
  }
];

const result = students.reduce((obj, student) => {
  const key = `${student.name}_${student.age}`;
  obj[key] = student;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

A generic approach that uses a callback to create the key:

```js
const keyBy = (arr, cb) => 
  arr.reduce((r, o) => {
    const key = cb(o);
    r[key] = o;
    return r;
  }, {});
  
const students = [{"name":"sam","age":26},{"name":"john","age":30}];  

const result = keyBy(students, (o) => `${o.name}_${o.age}`);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to the left side with a template literal like that. Try defining the property first, and then assigning it to the object:

```js
const students = [ { name: "sam", age: 26, }, { name: 'john', age: 30, } ];
const finalObj = students.reduce((obj, student) => {
  const prop = `${student.name}_${student.age}`;
  obj[prop] = student;
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(finalObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this script and it worked. Simply create variable name based on student name and age then assign back to the object

```
students.reduce((obj, student) => {
    var name = student.name + '-' + student.age;
    obj[name] = student;
    return obj;
  }, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this snippet will be useful

```js
const students = [{
    name: "sam",
    age: 26,
  },
  {
    name: "john",
    age: 30,
  }
]
//Using reduce function to add value to the accumalator
var x = students.reduce(function(acc, curr, index) {
  // Here acc is the object which is passed as argument,
  //In this object checking if it has a key like sam_26 & so on
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty([curr['name'] + '_' + curr['age']])) {
    //if not then add the key and add relevant vakues to it
    acc[curr.name + '_' + curr.age] = {
      name: curr.name,
      age: curr.age
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(x)
```